# Custom ag-grid cells in group

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I would like the cells of my grouping in ag-grid to be left justified.
Right now this is what I get:[image]

This is the definition of the colums or at least part of it:

```
 this.columnDefs = [
  { field: 'lot', rowGroup: true, hide: true, },
  {
    headerName: 'Titre', field: 'name', sortable: true, width: 150,
  },
```

I tried cellStyle and cellClass but nothing changes.
How could I fix that?

Comment: have you tried applying cellStyle to the autoGroupColDef?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this

```
::ng-deep .ag-theme-balham .ag-row-group .ag-cell{
justify-content: flex-start !important;
}
```

[image]